# Pentaho Data Integration inverting colors

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I can't see any field to fill, it's just blank.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and PDI 9.2.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiC1b.png)

Answer (score 0):

It was the theme of my computer. It was on dark theme and then the error happend.

I just changed the theme to standart and it worked!